# How to find battery usage of your iOS app

Tags: ios, iphone, profiling

How do I check the battery usage in my iOS app?

What is the right way to do power consumption profiling?

Comment: Thank you @Brian. I will take care of formatting the question correctly before posting.

Comment: You should also take care of accepting correct answers!

Answer (score 1):

xCode has a suite of instruments. One of them is called the energy usage and will give you metrics on your battery usage.

1. On the device: Go to Settings > Developer > Logging, and turn on logging.
2. Exercise your device as if you were a user.
3. After capturing the data, turn off developer logging.